# Nested structures and pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, nested

The compiler gives two complaints:

> error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'printout'
>
> warning: expected struct users *  but argument is of type 'users'

How do I fix these?
And please check if the function `printout` is OK.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
   char username[25];
   char firstname[25];
   char lastname[25];
   int age;
}users;

typedef struct{
   users data;
   int id;
}publicusers;

users createuser(char *uname, char *fname, char *lname, int fage);
void printout(users *data);

int main(){
    printout(createuser("kway","minseon","huh", 25));
    return 0;
}

users createuser(char *uname, char *fname, char *lname, int fage){
    publicusers user1;
    strcpy(user1.data.username, uname);
    strcpy(user1.data.firstname, fname);
    strcpy(user1.data.lastname, lname);
    user1.data.age = fage;
    return user1.data;
}

void printout(users *data){
    printf("username:  %s\n",data->username);
    printf("firstname: %s\n",data->firstname);
    printf("lastname:  %s\n",data->lastname);
    printf("age:       %d\n",data->age);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `createuser` function returns the `users` type and your function `printout` accepts `users*` as its argument which is a pointer to `users`.

Because you are declaring your struct `publicusers user1` inside your `createuser` function you cannot send its address as a return value. The fast solution is to change the function definition from:

```
void printout(users *data);
void printout(users *data){
   printf("username:  %s\n",data->username);
   printf("firstname: %s\n",data->firstname);
   printf("lastname:  %s\n",data->lastname);
   printf("age:       %d\n",data->age);
}
```

to

```
void printout(users data);
void printout(users data){
   printf("username:  %s\n",data.username);
   printf("firstname: %s\n",data.firstname);
   printf("lastname:  %s\n",data.lastname);
   printf("age:       %d\n",data.age);
}
```

This will create a copy of the struct `users`. If you want to avoid creating a copy you should consider creating `publicusers user1` in your main and send it as an extra argument to the `users createuser` function.

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: Another option, without changing any function signatures, is to use `users me = createuser("kway","minseon","huh", 25); printout(&me);` in `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your warning and error messages are generated from the following line:

```
printout(createuser("kway","minseon","huh", 25));
```

Function `printout` expects `user *` type value as its argument but function `createuser` returns `user` type value.

To fix this, you should pass `user *` type value as parameter using `&` operator. Change above one line code into two lines of code:

```
users u = createuser("kway","minseon","huh", 25);
printout(&u);
```

---

There's another way to fix this. You can change the parameter type of function `printout` from `user *` to `user`.

Your code should be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
   char username[25];
   char firstname[25];
   char lastname[25];
   int age;
}users;

typedef struct{
   users data;
   int id;
}publicusers;

users createuser(char *uname, char *fname, char *lname, int fage);
void printout(users data);                     // parameter type changed

int main(){
    printout(createuser("kway","minseon","huh", 25));
    return 0;
}

users createuser(char *uname, char *fname, char *lname, int fage){
    publicusers user1;
    strcpy(user1.data.username, uname);
    strcpy(user1.data.firstname, fname);
    strcpy(user1.data.lastname, lname);
    user1.data.age = fage;
    return user1.data;
}

void printout(users data){                     // parameter type changed
    printf("username:  %s\n",data.username);   // -> operator changed to . operator
    printf("firstname: %s\n",data.firstname);  // -> operator changed to . operator
    printf("lastname:  %s\n",data.lastname);   // -> operator changed to . operator
    printf("age:       %d\n",data.age);        // -> operator changed to . operator
}
```

Comment: The `printout(&createuser` is an error, the `&` operator can only be used on an lvalue